# getting warning when trying to remove api keys from old commits

Tags: git

I'm trying to remove API keys from my old commit, and I'm using this comment for that

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch 'workout_log/lib/key.properties'" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

But I'm getting this warning and nothing is removed.

> WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/main' is unchanged
> WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/main' is unchanged
> WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/main' is unchanged

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: You will be much happier using `filter-repo` or the BFG.

Comment: The warning occurs when the filter doesn't do anything. Apparently `'workout_log/lib/key.properties'` did not occur in any of the to-be-filtered commits. (This happens sometimes with case issues, especially on Windows and macOS, but there may be any number of stumbling blocks with filter-branch: it's a very klunky tool. Hence matt's recommendation of filter-repo, which is less klunky.)